# Encoding tif file to Base64 from InputStream

Tags: java, aws-lambda, tiff

I am trying to encode tif file retrieved from FTP using Java. The problem is, when I'm running my code in local server, tried both windows os and linux, only in windows worked successfully(encoded string is correct but when I uploaded it on AWS Lambda and done testing the encoded string is not being recognized by my decoder which is weird because it is working in local server).

Additional info:
When tried to change the file(tif) to jpeg and test in AWS, it worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i added file type setting in FTPClient and it works now!

`.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);`